# Phantom email unable to delete

Tags: ipad, email, ipados

I purchased a new iPad.  When I set up my Roadrunner email acct it downloaded over 300 from the main server to my inbox. I looked for a way to delete multiple email but there doesn't seem to be any method for that. As I was playing around with all the mailboxes, I did something because my inbox still says over 300 yet It only shows the current ones. ( I am keeping up to date deleting all incoming ) 
How do I find the phantom 300 ?  I've looked in every folder !

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain. I am also an RR client. Don't know if you are a native Apple person or if you are straddling the Windows-Apple barbed wire saddle. I wanted to share this with you, in case you ever look for an answer again (I see it was June when you posted). I found several "tips" about deleting lots of emails, but never like a "select all" and then deselecting a few you want to keep. [Ed: Duh. Why not build in a feature that consumers have led the market to KNOW is expected for maybe 2 decades now .... duh again, sorry for the redundancy)

Recently (viz. tonite) I deleted over 5000 emails from the iPad "mail" app. Took me almost 2 hours. It was much easier (and obviously successful) than following the exact steps in the online tips.

I open the native "mail" app. I select an inbox. I select "edit" so I can delete emails. I spend a lot of time [over and over] selecting one email at a time [this is where they could really help us out if they "allowed" some kind of a batch feature]. After selecting between 70-100 emails, I carefully select "move" - I say "carefully" because if you accidentally (I say this from repeated experience) get in a hurry, and select "move" as a single touch, nothing you do next will apply to all those dozens of hateful emails you want to delete.

So let's say you now have selected 86 emails, within the email app, in one inbox. Carefully SELECT-AND-HOLD-DOWN-FOR-SEVERAL-SECONDS "move" – you will see images of the group of emails layering on the right. You will next be taken to a screen listing WHERE to move these emails. Carefully select "trash". Boom - there they go, into the "trash", but they are not yet deleted. That is a separate step (see B below).

So, I did this repeatedly until I had about 300-400 emails in the trash. STEP B: Then you go back to the main menu for mail: select "trash". Select "edit" on the next page. At the bottom of the iPad screen, carefully select "delete" then VERY carefully select "delete all". I say again - carefully - because a hurried and careless "selection" (i.e., touch of the screen) will leave you nowhere you want to be - in short, undoing some aspect of all your efforts.

So - you delete individual emails by selecting them one at a time within the inbox [you will need to do this in the "sent" folder etc. if you want to remove other accumulations] - then you carefully move them to trash. Then after a little clutch of them are in the trash, open "trash" and select them and delete all of them.

Do this from 1 to 145,567 ... util all those dumb emails are gone.

What I want to know, is how to get rid of these 108 emails that “seem” to be in one inbox but they are nowhere to be found.

I have researched this for over a year, maybe close to 2 years now without success.

Good luck to us both.